# Kubernetes scaling of Client Applications

Tags: kubernetes, client, microservices

I am working on a solution for a Application which is running in a Kubernetes cluster. The Application creates similar OPC UA Client connections (TCP/IP) to similar OPC UA Servers. The challenge is to make the application scalable. If the load is high, the number of instances should be increased automatically. Does anyone has experience with such use case or an idea to solve the challenge?

Comment: Have you considered using [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)?

Answer (score -1):

As I already mentioned in the comments, you can use the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/):

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods
> in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set
> based on observed CPU utilization (or, with [custom metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md)
> support, on some other application-provided metrics).

The Autoscaler operates on the ratio between desired metric value and current metric value:

```
desiredReplicas = ceil[currentReplicas * ( currentMetricValue / desiredMetricValue )]
```

Therefore you will be able to scale up/down your app based on the load at the given time.

Also, see the [kubectl autoscale](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale) command:

> Creates an autoscaler that automatically chooses and sets the number
> of pods that run in a kubernetes cluster.

and a [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler Walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/) for a step by step guide with examples.

Comment: the problem with OPC-UA is that is not stateless